# What do I need to know from my client as freelance front end developer?

Tags: freelance-websites

ive been learning front end development for 2 months now, and thinking of getting a freelance job even just from a small scale business. I can now comfortably write html,css and use preprocessor also some jquery and js.. but i dont know how the process works on freelancing.. especially as a beginner what do i need to ask my client?

Comment: Spin it around - if you were the client, what would you expect to be asked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about development specifically. When will people learn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little secret to successful freelancing is that your **communication skills** (how your client perceives working with you) are just as important as your **technical skills** (what you actually perform for your client).

I'd say you need to ask your client(s) at least the following:

1. What are their requirements? Understand what problem they are trying to solve, what have they tried in the past, what worked and what did not.
2. What is their expected timeline? Are they expecting to complete your project in the next week, month, year?
3. Propose your deliverables. This is what you are promising to give them (for beginner freelancers, always add more detail than you expect), and in what timeframe. Have a discussion with them on which items are more or less important.
4. Propose your pricing and payment terms. Offer a few options so that your client can select from different levels of service you offer. Always get an initial deposit before you start work, and preferably progress payments as you reach certain milestones.
5. List a few basic conditions. For example, how much you charge if your client makes a change to the requirements, what you need from them (eg access to brand guidelines etc).

You mention "ask" so perhaps you are thinking this is mainly verbal. A verbal discussion is a great way to get things started, but you should always get an agreement in writing before starting work to minimize any disagreements.